# Battery on point and shoot film

Tags: film, battery, olympus, camera

Can I remove the battery on my olympus point and shoot film even if there is a film inside?

Comment: Can the battery be accessed without opening the film compartment?

Comment: What is the exact camera model? It's possible that the only negative effect will be that the camera loses count of how many exposures have been taken / are left.

Answer (score 2):

The camera battery compartment is separate from the light-tight area of the camera. This being the case, you can remove dead batteries and replace without harming the film.  You are advised to check the camera’s manual. When the battery dies or is near death, likely the camera stops functioning. Under these circumstances you will have little choice; you must charge or replace the battery.

Often, replacing or charging a complete dead battery resets the cameras logic. The film counter may revert to zero; the time and date may be lost. Again check with your camera manual.